# Sounds of fret scratches and pick

Tags: recording, sound

How valuable to a song are the sound of fret scratches, when the player lifts his fingers of the strings, and the sound of the pick? Is it better to leave them hearable or volume them down? How often do you hear these sound in songs?

Comment: This is a performance/recording question, and there's a (much more heavily trafficked) site devoted to that topic. http://music.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is also highly subjective. Some people like it some hate it. You should listen to the music you like to see how much of it you hear and decide whether you like it or not.

Comment: A song where they contribute to the mood is *Mandinka* by Sinéad O'Connor. I suspect she plays it with barré chords just to get that effect.  In many other similarly "loud" songs I find them unproblematic or even positive.  But for a classical guitar recording, you'd probably want to remove them.

Comment: @ChrisSunami How do I migrate this question to music.stackexchange.com?

Comment: A mod has to do it.  I'll see if I can get the attention of one of them:  @JohnnyBones